# How to overide the dropEvent of QstandardItem of a QListView to get position of the dragged object and position of the place where droped

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, overriding, qlistview

Here is my problem, I want to get the name, absolute position, and parent widget of an item from a QListView when drag and the QlistView widget where is been droped (and idealy the name or object of the item where it has been droped too).

For example with the code below : draging the item 'jaguar' on 'orange' should give me jaguar x=10 y=50 from widget "something" on orange x=30 y=70 from widget "somethingelse"

I tried to overide the function dropEvent of the QlistView but i get only the position of the QList viex not the item inside it.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QApplication, QListView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QIcon, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem


class CustomListView(QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **args):
        super(CustomListView, self).__init__(parent, **args)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.drag_item = None
        self.drag_row = None

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print("i was dropped")
        pos = event.pos()
        widget_dep = event.source()
        print("event position",pos.x(),pos.y())
        print("widget coordinate",widget_dep.x(),widget_dep.y())



### A custom widget containing my QlistView
class TableSelector(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, list_cols, checked=False):
        super(TableSelector, self).__init__(parent)

        self.name = name
        self.liste_cols = list_cols
        self.parent = parent
        self.main_frame = QVBoxLayout()

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView = CustomListView(self)
        # here is my problem i can never catch the event where i drag a row of the q list view
        # if i apply the next line i can drag and drop it but make a copy of the object in the other QlistViex and in just want the positions of both of the object.
        # self.listView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode)
        for col in self.liste_cols:
            item = QStandardItem(col)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setEditable(False)
            item.setDragEnabled(True)
            item.setDropEnabled(True)
            check = (Qt.Checked if checked else Qt.Unchecked)
            item.setCheckState(check)
            self.model.appendRow(item)

        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.main_frame.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.setLayout(self.main_frame)



class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dic_table = {"animaux": ["jaguar", "chien", "chat", "phasme", "tortue", "raptor"],
                          "fruit": ["bananne", "pomme", "pamplemousse", "kiwi", "orange", "fraise", "framboise",
                                    "poire", "groseille", "rhubarbe", "mangue", "litchee", "carambolle", "cerise",
                                    "prune", "figue", "goyave", "tamarin"]}

        self.mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        for table in self.dic_table.keys() :
            col_list = TableSelector(self, table, self.dic_table[table])
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(col_list)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: You should subclass the QListView and override its `dropEvent`, not that of the window. Also, those lines should not be static, but always updated depending on the item positions, because they could change if the views are scrolled.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante I thought i understood your advice but i can't manage to make it work. i simplified my code a lot so it is easier to understand what i am trying to do. Maybe you could give me an example on that ?

Comment: Use [`indexAt(pos)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#indexAt) to get the model index at a specific position.

Comment: @musicamante thanks, but how do i know which element was selected , the one which is dragged ?

Comment: Use [`selectedIndexes()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectedIndexes) of the source list view.